# Python coroutine that consumes and produces

Tags: python, coroutine

In a web-crawler of mine, I have a class that keeps track of urls to crawl, removing duplicates, etc:

```
class VisitOnlyOnceClerk(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = set()
        self.to_visit = set()

    def enqueue(self, url, referer):
        if not url in self.visited:
            self.to_visit.add((url, referer))

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.to_visit)

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.to_visit:
            (url, referer) = self.to_visit.pop()
            self.visited.add(url)
            yield (url, referer)
```

This provides an iterable that can also have values added to it:

```
clerk = VisitOnlyOnceClerk()
clerk.enqueue(starting_point, starting_point)
for (url, referer) in clerk:
    # get the url, and clerk.enqueue() all the links from it ...
```

This seems like a task that could be performed by a coroutine. I have seen examples of coroutines that solely produce values, and examples that solely consume values, but none that do both. Something like:

```
def visit_once_clerk():
    visited = set()
    to_visit = set([(yield)])

    for i in to_visit:
        visited.add(i[1])
        extras = (yield i)
        if extras:
            to_visit.union(i for i in extras if i[1] not in visited)
```

This, of course, does not work like I think it should. Are coroutines even the right tool here? What's the right way to use them in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think coroutine are the way to go here your class generator IMHO is way to much readable and understandable and easy to use than the way Python coroutine will allow you to do.

To make my point here is how i will implement the coroutine:

```
def visit_once_clerk(start_point=None):
    visited = set()
    to_visit = set(start_point or [])

    while to_visit:
        value = (yield to_visit.pop())
        if value and value not in visited:
            to_visit.add(value)
```

And here is how it should be used:

```
clerk = visit_once_clerk(['start'])
print clerk.next()   # Print: start
print clerk.send('test')  # Print: test
print clerk.next()   # Raise StopIteration
```

N.B: You can see that there is a difference between the two implementation specially the `send` and `enqueue` actions, the `send` action will yield the value send immediately **ITOH** `enqueue` will schedule the new value to be yield arbitrary (because of the use of a `set`)